# Replacing string by other with $1 - regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace like this:

```
"The price is {{price}}".replace(/\{{(.*?)\}}/, '$243')
//output: The price is $243
```

But whem I use something like $143, I got this: `"The price is price43"`

What is going on?

Comment: `$` indicates using a match in the replacement, try `$$` to escape it.

Comment: Its a duplicate. Thanks!